# How can I record the arrival order of agents in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

In my model I want one turtle breed (food) to record the order that a number of other breeds (predators) have arrived at it.

So far I have this piece of code that tells me who's there but doesn't preserve the order of arrival:

```
if ticks = day-length [
print [who] of turtles-here with [who != [who] of myself]
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated as always. I do have RNetLogo up and running if that offers a better method.

Thanks

One ugly way to get the data I'm after is to use two separate lines of code

```
  ask other turtles-here [show got-here]

  foreach   sort-by < [got-here]  of turtles-here with [shape = "default"]
  [
  show   ? 
  ]]
```

Comment: As a general comment, using `who` nearly always makes NetLogo code more complicated, not simpler. Instead, compare and manipulate turtles directly `turtles-here with [who != [who] of myself]` reduces to `turtles-here with [self != myself]` or just `other turtles-here`.

Answer (score 1):

You could save them as a list that the Food owns. But I think what would work best is have the Predators remember.

have the predators run something like this

```
if food-here != nobody and been-here = 0 [set got-here ticks]
```

the one with the lowest been-here has been there the longest.

check it like this

```
  ask food [print [who] of predators-here with-min[got-here]]
```

this is assuming that you are using ticks

to show a list

```
foreach sort-by < [got-here]
  [
  show ? ;; 
  ]
```

or better yet make a list

```
let here-list
foreach sort-by < [got-here]
  [
  set  here-list lput ? here-list
  ]
```

Comment: I'm almost there with your suggestion. The `with-min[got-here]` only gives me one value, the minimum. I can print the correct order with `show sort-by < [got-here] of turtles-here` but then I lose their identity

Comment: I will expand my answer to address this

Comment: Thanks for your responses. As it stands if I use your "to show a list" as follows:  `if any? turtles-here [if ticks = day-length - 10 [
    foreach sort-by < [got-here] of turtles-here with [shape = "default"]
  [
  show ?  
  ]]]` the code again gives me the ticks in the correct order but not the identity/ who of the agents.

Comment: try using who instead of ?

Comment: If I use who instead of ? it gives a list of the who number of the food which is the same length as the number of animals feeding on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96707/discussion-between-manassa-mauler-and-king-ink).

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to add a variable (say 'predator-order') to the `food-own` agent variable list if each piece of food is to record its own list. Then initialise the list to empty (`set predator-order []`) when the food is created. Don't use `who` in the list. Instead, add the agent to the list. Without seeing the surrounding code, it's hard to get the syntax right, but it will be something like:

```
ask this-food
[ set predator-order lput myself predator-order ]
```

Comment: Hi I tried this and got 'There is no agent for MYSELF to refer to.
error while food 4 running MYSELF'

Comment: as I said, I can't get the syntax right without seeing the surrounding code. However, I have assumed that you have something like `ask predators [move and eat and find food ....` Then somewhere in that code, you have that the predator is asking the food it has found to add itself (the predator) to the list. The `myself` refers to the predator who has asked the food ...